# Summing array elements in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

An exercise in Coderbyte is supposed to determine if some subset of integers in an array sum to the largest number in the array.

The following code seems to work on my computer, but when I submit it online, it seems to cause an endless loop. (There's never any output, regardless of the argument passed).

```
def arr_add?(arr)
  a = arr.sort
  lgst = a.pop
  size = a.size
  result = false
  while size > 1
    a.combination(size) {|c| result |= (c.inject {|r, a| r + a} == lgst)}
    size -= 1
  end
  result.to_s
end

arr_add?([1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 14])
```

Any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: any more details as to where you are submitting it ?

Comment: It's on Coderbyte.com. Here's the problem description: "Have the function ArrayAdditionI(arr) take the array of numbers stored in arr and return the string true if any combination of numbers in the array can be added up to equal the largest number in the array, otherwise return the string false. For example: if arr contains [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3] the output should return true because 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23. The array will not be empty, will not contain all the same elements, and may contain negative numbers."

Comment: Your code incorrectly returns `"false"` for `[0, 0, 5]`, for example.

Comment: @sawa Or just `[5]`.

Comment: @sawa: I see your point, but my problem is that the interpreter doesn't return either true or false (or anything else), regardless of the argument passed in.

Comment: Note that the problem statement itself is stupid: it is always the case that the 1-element combination consisting of the largest element sums to the largest element. So, it only really makes sense if we assume that we are *either* a) talking about the sum of the *rest of* the elements *except* the largest one or b) talking about combinations of at least size 2.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are actually *not* running into an endless loop, but rather just take a *really* long time, because of the inefficiency of your algorithm.

```
def ArrayAdditionI(arr)
  arr_size         = arr.size
  ary              = arr.sort
  largest          = ary.pop
  ary_size         = arr_size - 1
  combination_size = ary_size
  result           = false

  while combination_size > 1
    ary.combination(combination_size) {|combination| 
      result |= (combination.inject( 
        :+
      ) == largest)
    }
    combination_size -= 1
  end
  result.to_s
end
```

I introduced a new variable and renamed some others, so that it becomes easier to talk about the algorithm. I also reformatted it, to make the three nested "loops" more obvious.

Let's take a look at the algorithm.

The outer `while` loop is executed `ary_size - 1 == arr_size - 2` times, with `combination_size` ranging from `2` to `ary_size == arr_size - 1`.

The `combination` "loop" is executed **`ary_size` [choose](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html) `combination_size`** times, that's … well, a very quickly growing number.

The innermost "loop" (the operation performed by `combination.inject`) is executed `combination_size - 1` times.

This gives a total execution count for the innermost operation of:

- The Sum from `2` to `arr_size - 1` of
- `arr_size - 1` choose `combination_size` times
- `combination_size - 1`

In Wolfram Language, that's [`Sum[Binomial[a-1, c]*(c-1), c, 2, a-1]`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5Ba-1%2C+c%5D*%28c-1%29%2C+c%2C+2%2C+a-1%5D), which Wolfram Alpha tells us is `2^(a-2) (a-3)+1`, which is in O(2^n).

Playing around with the numbers a bit:

- for 10 items, we have 1793 executions of the `inject` operation
- for 15 items, we already have 98 305
- for 20 items, we have 4 456 449
- at 28 items, we cross the threshold to a billion operations: 1 677 721 601
- for 1000 items, which I suspect is a somewhat reasonable input size CoderBytes might use, we have 2 670 735 203 411 771 297 463 949 434 782 054 512 824 301 493 176 042 516 553 547 843 013 099 994 928 903 285 314 296 959 198 121 926 383 029 722 247 001 218 461 778 959 624 588 092 753 669 155 960 493 619 769 880 691 017 874 939 573 116 202 845 311 796 007 113 080 079 901 646 833 889 657 798 860 899 142 814 122 011 828 559 707 931 456 870 722 063 370 635 289 362 135 539 416 628 419 173 512 766 291 969 operations. Oops.

Try your algorithm with arrays of length 5, 10, 15 (all instantaneous), 20 (a noticeable pause), and then 23, 24, 25 to get a feel for just *how* quickly the runtime grows.

Assuming that you could build a CPU which can execute the inner loop in a single instruction. Further assuming that a single instruction takes only a Planck time unit (i.e. the CPU has a frequency of roughly 20 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 THz). Further assuming that every single particle in the observable universe was such a CPU. It will still take more than the current age of the universe to execute your algorithm for an array of not even 500 items.

Note that with most of these programming puzzles, they are not *actually* programming puzzles, they are mathematics puzzles. They usually require a mathematical insight, in order to be able to solve them efficiently. Or, in this case, recognizing that it is the [*Subset sum problem*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is known to be NP-complete.

By the way, as a matter of style, here is (a slight variation of) your algorithm written in idiomatic Ruby style. As you can see, in idiomatic Ruby, it almost becomes a 1:1 translation of the English problem statement into code.

While it is asymptotically just as inefficient as your algorithm, it breaks early, as soon as the answer is `true` (unlike yours, will just keep running even if it already found a solution). (`any?` will do that for you automatically.)

```
def ArrayAdditionI(arr)
  largest = arr.delete_at(arr.index(arr.max))
  1.upto(arr.size).any? {|combination_size|
    arr.combination(combination_size).any? {|combination|
      combination.inject(:+) == largest
    }
  }.to_s
end
```

This is an alternative interpretation of the (unclear) problem statement:

```
def ArrayAdditionI(arr)
  2.upto(arr.size).any? {|combination_size|
    arr.combination(combination_size).any? {|combination|
      combination.inject(:+) == arr.max
    }
  }.to_s
end
```

Comment: Wow. Some of this is over my head, but I really appreciate your taking the time to answer so thoroughly. As a beginner, I haven't even begun to consider issues of performance optimization, but this is very useful for drawing my attention to the issue. That being said, I don't think it's at the root of my problem here. I'm able to pass whatever arguments I want when testing the code, and the code returns nothing when given the input [1, 2, 3, 4, 10] which should be nearly instantaneous.

Comment: Well, a few things I have noticed: the problem statement on CoderByte is really bad. It is always the case that the 1-element combination which consists solely of the maximum element sums to the maximum element. So, that's probably not what they meant. However, there are *at least* two possible interpretations of what they *could have* meant: 1) they meant only combinations of size at least 2, or 2) they meant combinations of numbers *except* the maximum number. Another thing is that this is a well-known problem, called the *subset sum problem*, which is NP-complete, and thus impossible to …

Comment: … solve efficiently. Note that when I try your example `[1, 2, 3 ,4, 10]` with either your code, my expanded version of your code, or either one of my two implementations, it works just fine and returns `'true'` instantaneously. But for any larger arrays, it is just going to take a long time, there is no way around it, since the problem *is* hard.

Comment: I've had some similar problems with other challenges at Coderbyte. I.e., my attempted solution seems to work on my computer, but not when submitted online. I got in touch with someone over there and it turns out they're running Ruby 1.8.7, so I wonder if that could account for some of the discrepancy. They're due to update their version in the next couple of weeks, supposedly.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I tried installing MRI 1.8.7, but that version is so massively outdated and unmaintained that it won't even build on any OSX system newer than October, 2011. So, unfortunately, I can't verify your suspicion. However, I don't see anything obviously incompatible with Ruby 1.8.7 in your code. There's no use of `Fibre`, `Enumerator` or character encodings other than ASCII, no JSON-style `Hash` literals, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is valid ruby code.

The result is "true".

It is a bit unusual perhaps in that while loops are somewhat rare to see/have, but since it is valid ruby code, it should work on that remote site too.

Contact whoever runs the online ruby interpreter at Coderbyte - their version appears to be incompatible with the MRI ruby.

Your code seems to count down; perhaps have a look at 10.downto(1) - replace with variables as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I changed the while loop to this: "size.downto(2) {|n| a.combination(n) {|c| result |= (c.inject {|r, a| r + a} == lgst)} }". Still works in irb, but not on Coderbyte's interpreter. I'll see if I can get in touch with someone over there.

Comment: Hmmm... I changed the loop to this: "size.downto(2) {|n| a.combination(n) {|c| result |= (c.inject(:+) == lgst)} }" and everything works just fine. So it seems the problem was in the block passed to .inject ?